# Open Source Iris Scanning Library in Java

Tags: java, authentication, scanning

I am looking for suggestions about open source Iris Scanning libraries in Java. Has anyone used before which can built an unique profile for each scan & be able to authenticate too. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't used Java libraries that "just do" that entire work you describe, but it's not that difficult to use **JavaVis** (http://sourceforge.net/projects/javavis/) as in the sample code described in the following paper: http://imai-software.com/openlab/data/IMAI-JOUNALVI.pdf#page=43  (see from page 43) - that paper is quite good and for it's length :).

Of course, there are a few "working" solutions, e.g.:

- http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Math-Scientific/JIRRM.shtml (Java based)
- http://projectiris.co.uk/ (QT based -but there are more QT <-> Java bridges)

but personally I haven't used in production (just for testing) these 2 libraries since the documentation is not very good/detailed, and since this kind of problem is quite "cutting edge" so the documentation and an explanation paper is much more important than any source code.

If none of the above approaches work for you, I would suggest to use a MATLAB based iris recognition examples (because there are many MATLAB based implementations, papers, theses) and than convert them to Java or use the directly from Java (since MATLAB has support for this).

Comment: Link to the paper is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [OpenCV which is a C++ library for computer vision](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).   Java wrappers are available:

- [OpenCV Java and Processing library](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/)
- [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)

I believe you will want to look into Hough transforms for circles.  [This page](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bensapp/opencvdocs/ref/opencvref_cv.htm) mentions them

Answer (score 0):

IEEE material available , but it needs subscriptions.
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4579428

Answer (score 0):

I tried the project iris tool. It has the foundation blocks for IRIS Matching SYstem.
It has the following features:
* Basic QT UI
 - Needs qt-make and qt-sdk on top of gc++ and make to build
* Iris Detection from Image file. 
 - The Image should be 320x280 windows bmp greyscale 8 bit indexed image. 
 - You can take an iris snap from you camera phone. It took a 12M regular jpeg image and converted it to required format using gimp.
* Iris Image database: Text file db to store Iris Images. 
 - Means you could extend the tool to create a Iris Search database
 - I could take another iris image and try to match with existing image

Image acquisition is not available.